# React Native progress fill screen

Tags: react-native, flexbox

In my app, I am trying to display a progress bar using the `ActivityIndicator` upon a click event on a `TouchableHightlight` element. The problem is that I would like to have my progress bar fill up the whole screen (even filling up the spaces occupied by the navigation bar). Or if it is possible, a progress bar that takes up all the touch events on the screen while it is being displayed.

```
render()
{
    let progress;
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        progress = <ActivityIndicator style={[progressStyle.container, progressStyle.horizontal]}/>
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={{
                zIndex: 1,
                flex: 1,
                alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: "flex-start",
            }}>
                <View style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    alignItems: 'flex-end',
                    paddingTop: 5,
                    paddingHorizontal: 10,
                    marginBottom: 10
                }}>
                    <View style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        marginTop: 8,
                        marginBottom: 8
                    }}>
                        <Text style={labelStyle}>Name: </Text>
                        <TextInput
                            style={ textInputStyle }
                            value={ this.state.name }
                            onChangeText={(text) => {
                                this.setState({
                                    name: text
                                });
                            }} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        marginBottom: 8
                    }}>
                        <Text style={labelStyle}>Start Date: </Text>
                        <DatePicker
                            style={ datePickerStyle }
                            date={this.state.startDate}
                            mode="date"
                            placeholder="select start date"
                            format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                            confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                            onDateChange={(date) => {
                                this.setState({startDate: date});
                            }} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        marginBottom: 8
                    }}>
                        <Text style={labelStyle}>End Date: </Text>
                        <DatePicker
                            style={ datePickerStyle }
                            date={this.state.endDate}
                            mode="date"
                            placeholder="select end date"
                            format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                            confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                            onDateChange={(date) => {
                                this.setState({endDate: date});
                            }} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        marginBottom: 8
                    }}>
                        <Text style={labelStyle}>Max members: </Text>
                        <TextInput
                            style={ textInputStyle }
                            keyboardType="numeric"
                            value={ this.state.maxMembers }
                            onChangeText={(text) => {
                                this.setState({
                                    maxMembers: text
                                });
                            }} />
                    </View>
                    <View style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        flexDirection: 'row',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        marginBottom: 8
                    }}>
                        <Text style={labelStyle}>Available Until: </Text>
                        <DatePicker
                            style={ datePickerStyle }
                            date={this.state.availabilityDeadLine}
                            mode="date"
                            placeholder="select date til when this space is available"
                            format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                            confirmBtnText="Confirm"
                            cancelBtnText="Cancel"
                            customStyles={{
                                placeholderText:{
                                    textAlign: 'center'
                                }
                            }}
                            onDateChange={(date) => {
                                this.setState({availabilityDeadLine: date});
                            }} />
                    </View>
                </View>
                <ListOption
                    text="Create Room"
                    style={{
                        backgroundColor: (this.state.name!='' && this.state.startDate!='' 
                            && this.state.endDate!='' && this.state.maxMembers!='' 
                            && this.state.availabilityDeadLine!='')? Colors.tintColor : '#232323',
                        textColor: Colors.tintTextColor,
                    }}
                    onClick={
                        () => {
                            this.state.isLoading=true; this.setState({});
                            var tDate = new Date();
                            tDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
                            if(this.state.name != '' && this.state.startDate != '' && 
                                this.state.endDate != '' && this.state.maxMembers != '' && 
                                this.state.availabilityDeadLine != ''){
                                if(new Date(this.state.startDate) > new Date(this.state.endDate)){
                                    Alert.alert("start date cannot be after end date");
                                } else if(new Date(this.state.endDate) < tDate) {
                                    Alert.alert("end date cannot be before today");
                                } else if(new Date(this.state.availabilityDeadLine) < tDate) {
                                    Alert.alert("space has to be available at least up until today");
                                } else {
                                    //     this.state.isLoading = false;
                                    //     this.props.navigation.goBack();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } />
            </View>          
            {progress}
        </ScrollView>

    );
}
const progressStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      zIndex: 4,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      backgroundColor: '#565656',
      position: 'absolute',
      top:0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0
    },
    horizontal: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
      padding: 10
    }
})
```

I've tried giving `contentContainerStyle={{flex:1}}` to my `ScrollView` but I don't want my `ListOption` element to take up all the leftover space on screen and look fat. Right now, my `ActivityIndicator` takes up the whole of `ScrollView`, which is not taking up the whole screen.

So, will there be any way for me to give different `flex` abilities to the children of `ScrollView` element such that I can have my `ActivityIndicator` take up the whole screen while my `View` takes up as much as its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to wrap it inside a modal if you want it to fill the entire and set {width: "100%", height: "100%"}

Comment: Thanks @Mounir! Popping up a transparent modal works like charm but is there a reason behind why React Native will not allow a component in the screen to do it?